# Can php7.3 or apache2.4 log every file change/creation, to discover website vulnerabilities easily?

Tags: php, linux, apache, apache2.4, php-7.3

In a linux server with apache2.4 and php7.3 with many websites, I have the problem that one (or more) php script creates serveral files like "12345678.php" within bad code.
Is there a way to enable, on apache or php, the possibility to log which script is accessing the filesystem in write mode?

The goal is to have a log like:

> *date/time script_filename.php filename CREATE|WRITE*

so in this way I can find which script has a vulnerability.

Comment: `LogLevel debug` in Apache might help, look at `inotify` to monitor fileystem events.

Comment: How about PHP 7.4?